# Why the following python code always returning false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

***Input file Test.ini:***

```
;INTEGRITY_PERIOD=300  
INTEGRITY_PERIOD=100
```

**Code:**

```
key = None
value = None

with open('hmi.ini', 'r') as inifile:
    for line in inifile:
        if line.startswith(';INTEGRITY_PERIOD='):
            continue;
        if line.startswith('INTEGRITY_PERIOD='):
            key, value = line.split("=")
            break

if value and value.isdigit():
    print(value)
else:
    print(300)
```

The above code is always returning 300. Looks like isdigit() is not working or is there anything wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lines end in a *line separator*, which you did not remove. Strip the line to remove whitespace from the start and end:

```
key, value = line.strip().split("=")
```

A line separator (`\n`) is not a digit:

```
>>> '100\n'.isdigit()
False
>>> '100'.isdigit()
True
```

Rather than build your own parser, consider using the [`configparser` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) from the standard library. It fully supports the INI format (including using `;` as a comment).

Comment: When selecting the text in the provided code sample, it seems as though there are some spaces rather than a newline (though I'm not sure if this is just a formatting issue or not). When iterating over the lines, aren't newlines omitted automatically? Anyway, `.strip()` naturally handles any whitespace, be they spaces or newlines

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg: no, newlines are not omitted.

Comment: configparser module is really very useful. Thanks for letting me know about this library.